# How to access function from html onclick in .js file

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have this onclick function in my HTML file.

```
<button id="savetodb" onclick="savedb()">Save To Profile For later</button>
```

But I want to access it from my auth.js file. They are already connected

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="auth.js"></script>
```

Here is the auth.js function

```js
function savedb() {
      
}
```

The function doesn't work and I get this error
savedb' is declared but its value is never read.

Thanks

Comment: It just tells you that you never access it from anywhere. Please show the relevant code. Otherwise we cannot help you. Have a look here: [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Is your savedb function body empty?

Comment: that function is not accessible from an external js file. either put the function in a script tag inside the html file or use jquery run the function from an external file